# All sources readiness before data flows-in aross whole Flink job/data flow

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

If we have several sources in our data flow/job, and some of them implement `RichSourceFunction`, can we assume that `RichSourceFunction.open` of these sources will be called and complete before any data will enter into this entire data flow (through any of the many sources) - that is even if the sources are **distributed on different task managers**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink guarantees to call the `open()` method of a function instance before it passes the first record to that instance. The guarantee is scoped only to a function instance, i.e., it might happen that the `open()` method of a function instance was not called yet, while another function instance (of the same or another function) started processing records already.

Flink does not globally coordinate `open()` calls across function instances.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an advice how to coordinate 2 sources, one of configuration and the other of data? We must assure that configuration is in place before data starts to flow in. We could send a REST call the from config source to notify the data source it is ready, but maybe  you have a better idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no good solution for this in Flink yet. You can either 1) load the initial config in `open()`, i.e., not using a regular Flink source or 2) ship the initial configuration in a member variable of the function (which is serialized using Java's default serialization).